# Are there any easier ways to organize my favorites?

Tags: support, tags, bookmarks

May I ask are there any ways for users to categorize their favorites by self-written tags (not the official tags provided)?

E.g. in Biology Stack Exchange, a user is asking a question with the tag 'respiratory system', but the answer given involves something related to biochemistry, which I really like, but the user didn't tag it in his/her question. If I want to create my own tag for my own categorization purpose of favorites, how can I do it?

Answer (score 2):

> If I want to create my own tag for my own categorization purpose of favorites, how can I do it?

There's no support for this in Stack Exchange. You could use the extended bookmark functionality of your browser to create a 'biochemistry' folder and add the question to it.